# Working out a basic score from integer values

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to work out a basic % value by gathering values together:

```
   For Each M As Match In matchFound
       lamdaFix2 = M.Groups(1).Value
       lamdaFix3 = M.Groups(2).Value
       Application.DoEvents()
       Dim lv As ListViewItem = formMozCheck.listViewMoz.Items.Add(lamdaFix1)
       lv.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
       lv.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(Double.Parse(lamdaFix2)).ToString())
       lv.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(Double.Parse(lamdaFix3)).ToString())
       lv.SubItems.Add("-")
       lv.SubItems.Add("-")
       lv.SubItems.Add(itm.SubItems(8).Text)
       Dim srVal As Integer
       If (itm.SubItems(9).Text = "") Then
           srVal = 0
       Else
           srVal = CInt(itm.SubItems(9).Text)
       End If
       lv.SubItems.Add(srVal.ToString())
       ' work out a score
       Dim overAllScore As Integer
       ' TODO: basic score
       overAllScore = CInt(CInt(CDbl(Math.Round(Double.Parse(lamdaFix2)).ToString()) & CDbl(Math.Round(Double.Parse(lamdaFix3)).ToString()) & CDbl(itm.SubItems(8).Text) & Val(srVal)) * 100)

       lv.SubItems.Add(CLng(overAllScore) & "%").ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
       itm.Checked = False
   Next
```

These values:

```
lv.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(Double.Parse(lamdaFix2)).ToString())
lv.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(Double.Parse(lamdaFix3)).ToString())
```

Are values between 0 - 100

And these ones:

```
itm.SubItems(8).Text
itm.SubItems(9).Text
```

Are values between 1 - 10

I have been racking the brains to see what the best way to add these values up and give a basic percentage, my attempt:

```
overAllScore = CInt(CInt(CDbl(Math.Round(Double.Parse(lamdaFix2)).ToString()) & CDbl(Math.Round(Double.Parse(lamdaFix3)).ToString()) & CDbl(itm.SubItems(8).Text) & Val(srVal)) * 100)
```

Just adds all values like 234524 rather than the total value of 23+45+2+4

i'm probably over complicating this lol

i tagged it as both vb and c# as i though the logic would be the same ;)

thanks for any help guys!

Graham

Comment: Start to loose this attitude to make everything in a single line. Use proper double variables that receive the conversion from the strings. Make the math with these double variables and then convert your result to a suitable string for your listview

Answer (score 0):

You should use "+" instead of "&":

```
overAllScore = CInt(CInt(CDbl(Math.Round(Double.Parse(lamdaFix2)).ToString()) + CDbl(Math.Round(Double.Parse(lamdaFix3)).ToString()) + CDbl(itm.SubItems(8).Text) + Val(srVal)) * 100)
```